# Ecclesiastical Latin pronunciation of "excelsis": /e/ or /ɛ/?

Tags: pronunciation, ecclesiastical-latin

My question is about pronunciation of both *e*'s in the word *excelsis* in Ecclesiastical Latin.

Here is an excerpt of a [previous question in this site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/8781/6540):

> A final postscript: although what I've *heard* is that *excelsis* is pronounced in the Christmas carol is [ɛksʧɛlsis], wouldn't [ɛkʃɛlsis] be the "correct" Ecclesiastical pronunciation?

There is a comment by an Italian user that asserts that the answer to this question is "no", but what I want to remark is that it seems to be assumed that both *e*'s in the word *excelsis* are pronounced /ɛ/.

I've also found this [other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/8790/) which states that these *e*'s are both pronounced /ɛ/.

Now, looking at the entry [*excelsis* at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excelsis), I've surprisingly found the following phonetic transcription for Ecclesiastical Latin:

> /eksˈt͡ʃel.sis/

But there is also an alternative in brackets:

> [ɛksˈt͡ʃɛl.sis]

Maybe the problem is that I don't understand how Wiktionary works. I've tried to get it looking at this [Appendix about Latin pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_pronunciation), but I'm really confused. They seem to make a distinction between 100 BC and 100 AD, but in this case it seems not to make sense because, as far as I know, Ecclesiastical Latin was developed later, in the [Middle Ages](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13984/).

The [Wiktionary article about International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:International_Phonetic_Alphabet) contains what I would expect about pronunciation of /e/ or /ɛ/.

Another problem is that I have heard lots of people and ensambles that were singing with an Ecclesiastical Latin pronunciation, but, unfortunately, their pronunciation is not always good.

Can anyone enlighten me about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not alternatives, strictly speaking: the transcription between slashes /.../ is a *phonemic* transcription, while the one between brackets [...] is a *phonetic* transcription.

Phonemic transcription is not concerned with pronunciation, only with underlying phonemes, so the choice of a specific notation for a phoneme depends less on the actual phonetic quality in practice than it does on the author's conception of clarity and convenience. The pronunciation of *e* in Ecclesiastic Latin is indeed [ɛ], but the phoneme that it reflects is conventionally written as /e/, perhaps just because it's easier to type, or reflects the spelling more.

Comment: Oh, I now see that [Wiktionary article about Pronunciation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Pronunciation) states that phonemic transcriptions are given within slashes. However, it gives this phonemic transcription of the word *better* in non-rhotic accents of English: /ˈbɛt.əɹ/. Isn't this an inconsistency?

Comment: @Charo Regarding the vowels? /ɛ/ and /ə/ are different phonemes in English; there's a minimal pair in *bet* /bɛt/ and (unstressed) *but* /bət/. In other languages [ɛ] and [ə] might be allophones of the same phoneme, in which case you'd use the same phonemic transcription for both there (possibly /ɛ/). A phoneme is a phoneme in a specific language, not across all languages.

Comment: That said, a lot of eager Wikipedians are very confused about the difference between phonemic and phonetic transcriptions, and even people who should know better sometimes think of /.../ as broad (i.e. less precise) phonetic transcription compared to [...]'s narrow transcription, and you'll inevitably run into clear misuse of IPA *somewhere*.

Comment: I was simply referring to the use of d /ɛ/ instead of /e/ in this phonemic transcription.

Comment: @Charo People are free to use whatever transcription they like as long as it's consistent (and, ideally, eventually a consensus emerges and you get a set of conventions to use in a specific language). You could use /e/ for [ɛ] if you wanted to, but English in particular has a lot of e-like sounds, so the extra effort required to type ɛ might pay off in a reduction in confusion with other phonemes.

Comment: Just another question, @Cairnarvon. For Ecclesiastical Latin, do we have to assume that both vowel sounds [e] and  [ε] are phonemic transcribed at Wiktionary as /e/? Isn't that confusing?

Comment: @Charo I'm not an expert on E. Latin but AFAIK it doesn't have [e]. It certainly lost the contrastive vowel length of Classical Latin, collapsing long and short *e* (/eː/ [eː] and /e/ [ɛ]; here /e/ rather than /ɛ/ to indicate that the two phonemes are closely related, one meaningfully being the short version of the other) into a single phoneme. But yes, in general, a single phoneme can have multiple pronunciations (allophones), and a phonemic transcription won't tell you how a word is pronounced unless you're very familiar with a language's phonology—hence the separate phonetic transcription.

Comment: Some English dictionaries do use /e/ in "better", so unfortunately there is no set convention on how to phonemically transcribe English. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/better?q=Better